# Change a url parameter value

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have a string that contains a URL i.e. `.../details?fname=peter&lname=smith&...`

Is there a way to replace the `lname` parameter value in the URL with another? Keeping in mind that `lname` value is not always the same.

Comment: You mean to say. You need to replace the 2 nd Parameter value always ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789093.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Use static **ParseQueryString()** method of **System.Web.HttpUtility** class that returns NameValueCollection.

```
string url = "http://example.com/file?a=1&b=2&c=string%20param";
string querystring = url.Substring(url.IndexOf('?'));
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameters = 
   System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string replace. For example, if you need to build a customized url you can do something like this:

```
string myURL = ".../details?fname=peter&lname=#lname#";

string myValue ="finalvalue";

string FinalURL = myURL.Replace("#lname#,myValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Dim sAux() As String = sURL.Split(New Char() {"?"c, "&"c})
Dim sParams() As String

For Each elem As String In sAux
    sParams = elem.Split("="c)
    If sParams(0).Equales("lname", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
        sUrl = sUrl.Replace("lname=" & sParams(1), "lname=" & sNewValue)
    End If
Next
```

Or simply:

```
Dim index As Integer = sUrl.IndexOf("lname=")
Dim auxIndex As Integer = sUlr.IndexOf("&", index + 1)
Dim sAux As String

If index >= 0 Then
    If auxIndex < 0 Then
        sAux = sUrl.Substring(index)
    Else
        sAux = sUrl.SubString(index, sUrl.Length - auxIndex)
    End If

    sUrl = sUrl.Replace(sAux, "lname=" & sNewValue)
End If
```